# Date format conversion javascript

Tags: javascript

Consider if we have a date in the format `Sat Jul 28 2012` , is there a general a function to convert it in to any wanted format??

say for example `28-07-2012`,

deciding the separators like - or /

Answer (score 1):

Javascript's Date object has *lots* of different versions of `toString` and different getters, so it should be pretty easy to get the output you want. Scroll down through [this documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date#Methods) to see some of your options. They have pretty good examples too if you click on them.

In addition, the Date constructor is fairly good at taking in most strings and converting it.

```
var myDate = new Date("Sat Jul 28 2012");
alert(myDate.toLocaleDateString());
```

Or use the different getters and string concatenation wrapped in a function to make your own.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a function to do it, i dont think there is a Native method:

```
function convert(dateObj) {
   var format = dateObj.getFullYear()+"-";
   format += dateObj.getMonth()+"-";
   format += dateObj.getDate();
   return format;
}
```

you can customize it however you want. here is the [list of methods for the date object](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp)

Answer (score -1):

Javascript only outputs it into the standard format you provided above. You can try using the `getDate()`, `getDay()`, `getMonth()` methods (among others) to extract the necessary data and convert it to your liking.

Please refer to [W3Schools' description of the JavaScript Date object](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp).

Comment: [Try to avoid w3schools](http://w3fools.com/) for JS docs. Point to [the MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) instead